# Parsing error: Unexpected keyword 'export' in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs

In my index.js file under 'store', I have the following code:

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
// import axios from 'axios'

const createStore = () => {
  return new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      loadedPosts: []
    },


//... [more code]
//... [more code]
//... [more code]
//...

export default createStore
```

I've received an error message stating parsing error: unexpected keyword 'export'

Does anyone know what this means? The error occurs on the last line of the file below:

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
// import axios from 'axios'

const createStore = () => {
  return new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      loadedPosts: []
    },


    mutations: {
      setPosts (state, posts) {
        state.loadedPosts = posts
      },
      addPost (state, post) {
        state.loadedPosts.push(post)
      },
      editPost (state, editedPost) {
        const postIndex = state.loadedPosts.findIndex(post => post.id === editedPost.id)
        state.loadedPosts[postIndex] = editedPost.id
      },
      setToken (state, token) {
        state.token = token
      },
      clearToken (state) {
        state.token = null
      }
    },


    actions: {
      nuxtServerInit (vuexContext, context) {
        return context.app.$axios
          .$get('/posts.json')
          .then((data) => {
            const postsArray = []
            for (const key in data) {
              postsArray.push({ ...data[key], id: key })
            }
            vuexContext.commit('setPosts', postsArray)
          })
          .catch(error => context.error(error))
      },

      addPost (vuexContext, post, res) {
        const createdPost = {
          ...post,
          updatedDate: new Date()
        }
        return this.$axios
          .post(process.env.baseURL + '/posts.json?auth=' + vuexContext.state.token, createdPost)
          .then((data) => {
            vuexContext.commit('addPost', { ...createdPost, id: data.name })
            this.$router.push('/admin')
          })
          // .catch(error => console.log(error))
      },

      editPost (vuexContext, editedPost) {
        return this.$axios.$put(process.env.baseURL + '/posts.json' + editedPost.id + '.json?auth=' + vuexContext.state.token, editedPost)
          .then((res) => {
            vuexContext.commit('editPost', editedPost)
          })
          // .catch(error => console.log((error)))
      },

      setPosts (vuexContext, posts) {
        vuexContext.commit('setPosts', posts)
      },

      authenticateUser (vuexContext, authData) {
        if (!authData.isLogin) {
          return this.$axios.$post('https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=' + process.env.fbAPIKey, {
            email: this.email,
            password: this.password,
            returnSecureToken: true
          })
            .then(result => console.log(result))
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
        } else if (authData.isLogin) {
          return this.$axios.$post('https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=' + process.env.fbAPIKey, {
            email: authData.email,
            password: authData.password,
            returnSecureToken: true
          })
            .then((result) => {
              vuexContext.commit('setToken', result.idToken),
              localStorage.setItem('token', result.idToken),
              localStorage.setItem('tokenExpiration', new Date().getTime() + result.expiresIn * 1000)
              vuexContext.dispatch('setLogoutTimer', result.expiresIn * 1000)
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
        }
      },

      setLogoutTimer (vuexContext, duration) {
          setTimeout (() => {vuexContext.commit ('clearToken')}, duration)
        },

        initAuth (vuexContext) {
          const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
          const expirationDate = localStorage.getItem('tokenExpiration')

          if (new Date().getTime() > +expirationDate || !token) {
            return
          }
          vuexContext.dispatch('setLogoutTimer', +expirationDate - new Date().getTime())
          vuexContext.commit('setToken', token)
    }
    },

    getters: {
      loadedPosts (state) {
        return state.loadedPosts
      },
      isAuthenticated (state) {
        return state.token != null
      }
    }
  })
},

export default createStore
```

Error occurs at export default createStore where it's saying parsing error: unexpected keyword 'export'.  Removing the comma before export default creates more errors which refer to the .then(result) => section.  It's telling me that localStorage.setItem's are 'expecting assignment or function calls instead of expressions' if I remove the comma before 'export default createStore.'

Comment: please share your `package.json`

Comment: Hi @BoussadjraBrahim - I've edited the post to include the package.json file

Comment: ok, the package.js looks good, please share the whole code inside the `index.js` in store fplder

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim - I've just posted the complete index.js file

Comment: remove the `,` before `export` which causes this issue

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim , if I remove the comma I get errors in the '.then((result) => ' section.  It's telling me that localStorage.setItem's are 'expecting assignment or function calls instead of expressions':    .then((result) => {
              vuexContext.commit('setToken', result.idToken),
              localStorage.setItem('token', result.idToken),
              localStorage.setItem('tokenExpiration', new Date().getTime() + result.expiresIn * 1000)
              vuexContext.dispatch('setLogoutTimer', result.expiresIn * 1000)
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the `,` before `export` and assign the data to your localStorage item as follows :

```
 localStorage['tokenExpiration']= new Date().getTime() + result.expiresIn * 1000
```

Comment: I've modified your answer slightly but it now works - thanks for that

Comment: you're welcome, yes you could also do ` localStorage.tokenExpiration`

Answer (score 0):

I removed `,` before `export` and it works! Thank you, Boussadjra Brahim :D

This is what my code looks like now:

```
 // some.js

 const title = [
{...},
{...},
{...},
]
        
export { title };
```